# How to align text to left in Medium Widget Extension in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, widget

I am trying to add widgets to my app and I am very new to this, I am showing 3 links in the medium Widget extension and the problem is all 3 links are in the centre and I want them to align on left side, I have tried many things which are available online but still not working,
this is my code :

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            Image("background")
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                .frame(width: geo.size.width,
                       height: geo.size.height,
                       alignment: .center)
            }
        
        switch family{
        case .systemSmall:
            Text(entry.date, style: .time)
                        .widgetURL(URL(string: "fcv://open_activity"))
        case .systemMedium:
            VStack (alignment: .leading){
                               Link(destination: URL(string: "game:///link1")!, label: {
                                   Text("Link1")
                                       .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                                   
                                      
                               })
                               Spacer()
                               Link(destination: URL(string: "game1:///link2")!, label: {
                                   Text("Link2")
                                       .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                                       
                               })
                               Spacer()
                               Link(destination: URL(string: "game2:///link3")!, label: {
                                   Text("Link3")
                                       .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                                      
                               })
                           }
                           .padding()
        default:
            Link(destination: URL(string: "fcv2://open_activity")!) {
                Text("Link 4")
            }
```

I have tried this:

```
.font(.body)
.fontWeight(.bold)
.lineLimit(1)
.allowsTightening(true)
```

and also this:

```
 .zIndex(2)
 .shadow(radius: 5)
```

but neither of them work.

Comment: have you try to add .padding(.zero) to the Link?
Like:
Link(destination: URL(string: "game:///link1")!, label: {
                                   Text("Link1")
                                       .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)                               }).padding(.zero)

Comment: not working,,, @linhlê